# jquery focusout not adding text back in

Tags: jquery, jquery-focusout, focusin

I have a textarea that has some text in it on page load.  When someone clicks on it I'd like for that text to go away.  When they click out of it, if they haven't typed anything I'd like the text to come back, but if they have for nothing to happen.  The text is 'Type your answer here".  This is what I have which works for removing the text on click but not for adding it back in if they haven't typed anything.

```
$(".area-3").focusin(function() {
     $(".area-3").text(" ");
 }).focusout(function() {
    if ($(".area-3").val().length == 0) {
     $(".area-3").text("Type your answer here.");
    } 
 });
```

thanks so much for any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$(".area-3").on({
    focus: function() {
       if (this.value == 'Type your answer here.') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function() {
       if ( $.trim(this.value) == '') this.value = 'Type your answer here.';
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KM3rX/)

Comment: is the use of ".on" considered better practice?

Comment: +1 all round nicer answer than mine, plus you added the check for the value on focus.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+, `on()` would be the preferred way to attach event handlers.

Comment: would you mind explaining one thing to me? Normally for an if statement I would type if (something here) { something here} is what you've typed with if (something here) something here;  exactly the same thing?

Comment: Yes it is, if the value is `Type your answer here.` and someone focuses on the textarea, set the value to an empty string, it the value is an empty string, set the value to `Type your answer here.` , you can test it out in the fiddle.